# How to send a message to all the persons (viewers or editors) of a Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have Googles docs (slides, sheets, docs) that are shared with some people and I would like to send them a message.

I tested the comment, the feature is very good for my use case because I can specify the exact cell (for google sheet) that I want to comment.

**But users seem not to receive a notification.**

I can get all the email addresses and send an email, but the number of emails can be too high. And I can't specify the cell for which I want to comment.

And I can't find another way. Do you have some ideas ? Thank you

Comment: Have you considered chunking the email list if it's over a certain amount?

Comment: I update my question. Emailing is not my preferred option, since I would like to comment specific texts (google doc) or cells (for google sheet)

Comment: U use the @theuser inside the mention? I always get a message.

Comment: for one user, it is OK. But it is possible to send to all?

Comment: If you want something like @all so it can notify everyone within the sheet I'm afraid that the feature doesn't exist. As such you could submit feedback on the public [Help Center article](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/65129?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cadd-a-comment%2Csend-a-comment-to-a-specific-person)

Answer (score 0):

I just used file->email->email collaborators. It will send an email to all collaborators on the document so all viewers and editors